# Read file with unknown encoding

Tags: python, file, encoding, file-io, character-encoding

I'm trying to load the columns of a file with a strange encoding. Windows appears to have no issues opening it, but Linux complains and I have only been able to open it using the [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor (others give me either a blank file or a file with data encoded)

The command:

```
file -i data_file.tit
```

returns:

```
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

Opening the file in binary mode and reading the first 400 bytes gives:

`'0905077U1- a\r\nIntegration time: 19,00 ms\r\nAverage: 25 scans\r\nNr of pixels used for smoothing: 2\r\nData measured with spectrometer name: 0905077U1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\nWave   ;Dark     ;Ref      ;Sample   ;Absolute Irradiance  ;Photon Counts\r\n[nm]   ;[counts] ;[counts] ;[counts] ;[\xb5Watt/cm\xb2/nm]       ;[\xb5Mol/s/m\xb2/nm]\r\n247,40;-1,0378;18,713;10,738;21,132;0,4369\r\n247,'`

The rest of the file consists only of ASCII numbers separated by semicolons.

I tried the following ways to load the file:

```
with open('data_file.tit') as f:
    bytes = f.read() # (1)
    # bytes = f.read().decode('???')  # (2)
    # bytes = np.genfromtxt(f)  # (3)
    print bytes
```

- `(1)` Sort of works but skips the first several hundred lines.
- `(2)` Failed with every [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) I tried with the error:

  ```
  codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 315: unexpected special character
  ```
- `(3)` Complains about `ValueError: Some errors were detected !` and shows for each line something similar to `Line #3 (got 3 columns instead of 2)`.

How can I load this data file?

Comment: We cannot possibly know. You have random data, we are not clairvoyants I am afraid.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what do you mean? I posted a link to the file, I'm not hiding it.

Comment: Your question needs to be self-contained however; don't expect people to download random data from the internets! And guessing at the encoding of your file is not going to be helpful to anyone else.

Comment: How else can I share the data file? If I paste the contents here, won't they be overwritten or the encoding changed by the page? And finding a way to tell the encoding is part of the question.

Comment: `repr()` can give you Python representations of the data. Open the file in binary mode (`'rb'`) and give us a sample perhaps.

Comment: For what it is worth, the file is just Windows CP-1252 data with a few nulls.

Comment: Using `.decode('cp1252')` returns: `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb5' in position 315: ordinal not in range(128)`. Am I doing something wrong? I'm checking out this `repr()` command you mentioned.

Comment: You are trying to do this on a Unicode string, *already decoded*, which means it'll try to automatically *encode* first.

Comment: I tried Leafpad, Geany, Scratch, Sublime and Atom. The latter was the only one that opened the file correctly. I might be missing some fonts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a [codepage 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoded text file, with one line containing NULL bytes. The `file` command determined you have binary data on the basis of those NULLs, while I made an educated guess on the basis of the `\xb2` and `\xb5` codepoints, which stand for the `²` and `µ` characters.

To open, just decode from that encoding:

```
import io

with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.rstrip('\n\x00'))
```

The first 10 lines are then:

```
0905077U1- a
Integration time: 19,00 ms
Average: 25 scans
Nr of pixels used for smoothing: 2
Data measured with spectrometer name: 0905077U1
Wave   ;Dark     ;Ref      ;Sample   ;Absolute Irradiance  ;Photon Counts
[nm]   ;[counts] ;[counts] ;[counts] ;[µWatt/cm²/nm]       ;[µMol/s/m²/nm]
247,40;-1,0378;18,713;10,738;21,132;0,4369
247,57;3,0793;19,702;9,5951;11,105;0,2298
247,74;-0,9414;19,929;8,8908;16,567;0,3430
```

The NULLs were stripped from the *Data measured with spectrometer name: 0905077U1* line; the spetrometer name is now 9 bytes long, together with the 55 NULLs it looks like the name could be up to 64 characters long and the file writer didn't bother to strip those NULLs.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn. When I try this I get: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb5' in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)`. The issue is with the $\mu$ chars in line 7 I believe. Is there a way to skip reading these?

Comment: @Gabriel: you are trying to decode data that is already Unicode. Don't do that.

Comment: I'm just trying to read the file using your answer, nothing else I swear. I don't know why I get that error, I've tried stripping those characters using `\xb5` instead of `\n\x00` in your answer but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Gabriel: Are you using `io.open()`? Or is the exception thrown when *printing*? What console are you using to print in that case? Not everything can handle non-ASCII printing.

Comment: @Gabriel: try `print line.rstrip('\n\x00').encode('ascii', 'replace')`; that'll force an encoding to ASCII ignoring the 4 non-ASCII characters. That way you can at least see the file contents.

Comment: Yes! That last line finally worked. Thank you very much Martijn!

Comment: @Gabriel: then your *console* or *terminal* can only handle ASCII output.

Answer (score 5):

Guessing an encoding can be really hard, luckily there's a library that tries to help with that: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet

Comment: May be a stupid question, but can't you use try: except: repeatedly with different guesses at the encoding until you get no errors?  Would this work?  I'm writing code that reads csv files but for a client that will be creating his own files so I have no idea what encoding they might be in.  Thanks.

Comment: Not stupid, but also not Pythonic. chardet does the trick, so just use it.