# How to decode .dat files with unknown encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to read some .dat files into Pandas but I don't know the encoding of the binary data.

The only way I can get Pandas to read this files without raising exceptions is this:

```py
for chunk in pd.read_csv(data_file, index_col=False, sep=r'\s\s+', chunksize=10**3, engine="python"):
        print(chunk)
        break
```

Which returns:

```py
           4.2DABCDEFGHSnRbTs
0    ����@�\t�<\t��P��...
1                                        N DEN TAA
2    ��@<<J8TE�nnJ8@��N TA���`A"�UR...
3    �@DF((4PP�PP��DEZZ�PX22�PDE22u0@A�...
4                                 u0TEݠ<'Pd<��@
..                                                 ...
737                                             �PTF\
738                 pTB�(("�Pn22�pTE\�TF�
739                                    �8@F�PҨ@�
740  n�`DP��P��[`DA�x�DA�ZZ]�Td<(w...
741  "�URc,�8�A<,�(TUc�ix@��m`T�...

[742 rows x 1 columns]
```

If I try this for the first three files I'm trying to decode:

```py
with open(data_file, "rb") as f:
    data = f.read(100)
    print(data)
```

This is what I get:

```py
b'\x00\x034.2\x00\x01D\x00\x08ABCDEFGH\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06SnRbTs\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbb\xbb\x00\x00\x00\xf6\xca@\xd2\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\xf1<\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\xef\xd4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01L\x08P\x05\x0e\xe1\xf0P\xd6\xd8D'
b'\x00\x034.2\x00\x01D\x00\x08ABCDEFGH\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06SnRbTs\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbb\xbb\x00\x00\x00\xf6\xcaA\x04d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\xea&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\xe8\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xd4\xc0P\x06\x0b~\xb4\x8c\x00\x1e]'
b'\x00\x034.2\x00\x01D\x00\x08ABCDEFGH\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06SnRbTs\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbb\xbb\x00\x00\x012\x81\xe1\x0b,\x00\x00\x00\x02\xad\xd9\xd9\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x02\xad\xd9\xd9\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x86\xa0R$\nE\x00,\x8e@\x00'
```

I've tried using [`chardet`](https://github.com/chardet/chardet) and [`charset_normalizer`](https://github.com/ousret/charset_normalizer) but they both failed to recognize any encoding. I've also tried to manually run `data.decode(enc, 'ignore')` for all encodings supported in Python, and I manually checked if any of the results weren't absolute gibberish, but that also didn't work.

Keep in mind that I'm expecting the files to have this format:

```py
datetime,ask,bid,vol
2017-01-02,134.44,134.58,89
2017-01-03,134.34,134.58,85
...
```

So maybe this is confusing `chardet` and `charset_normalizer`, as I think they work best on normal language.

Any ideas?

Comment: Dosen't this look like this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26122007/read-file-with-unknown-encoding?

Comment: I tried to replicate exactly the accepted solution, and I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1236: character maps to <undefined>`. If I change the encoding to `cp850` instead, I get this result for the first line: `'\x00\x034.2\x00\x01D\x00\x08ABCDEFGH\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06SnRbTs\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n'`